# How do I ping virtual machines that are connected to my host pc?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, hosts

I have installed VirtualBox on my pc. I have "Virtual Host-Only Network" virtual network card and two connected machines to it via Host-Only network mode.

I want to check their addresses from host, an then I want to ping each machine from host.

**EDIT:**

(note: I work on Windows, so instead of grep I used find)

I have used these commands (first line is command, next is result):

```
VBoxManage list vms
"MyMachine1" {uuid1}
"MyMachine1" {uuid2}
```

Next was

```
VBoxManage showvminfo "MyMachine1" | find "NIC"
NIC 1: MAC: _MAC_ADDRESS, ..., 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3", ...
NIC 2: disabled
NIC 3: disabled
NIC 4: disabled
```

Then
    arp -a | find "_MAC_ADDRESS"
(In this command, I had to separate MAC digits with "-" as arp displays it like AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF)

I guess I am close, but this last command does not give any result like there was no _MAC_ADDRESS; but other addresses are displayed correctly.

**EDIT 2:**

Finally I got this :) thanks for help, malevolent, you're awesome.

What I did:

```
VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate "MyMachine1" | find "IP"
Name: /VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP, value: 192.168.56.100, timestamp: 1452501107090249101, flags:
```

Fair enough for me :)

But malevolent made this in a more elegant way, with regular expressions (see his answer). It could be useful when you really need to stripe down result to get IP address and use it in some tricks, hacks and scripts :)

HUUGE THANKS BRO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Turn on the VM**

First of all, you should turn on the guest VMs, make sure you have them turned on with

```
VBoxManage list runningvms
```

If no machine is listed, you have no VMs turned, on, list them and turn them on with

```
VBoxManage list vms
"Windows7" {4968bf9e-cef5-4146-85e7-431c4a0d6d6c}

VBoxManage startvm name_of_VM
```

Where name_of_VM is the name of your Virtual Machine.

**Without VirtualBox Guest additions installed.** (no internet connection needed)

You have the command VBoxManage. To show all the VM informations you should run:

```
VBoxManage showvminfo "name_of_VM"
```

Once you have the information from the VM's, write down the MAC address, for example:

```
NIC 1:           MAC: 080027CD3159, Attachment: Bridged Interface 'enp1s0f0', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: 82540EM, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none
```

Then, you can use arp command like this, changing the _MAC_ADDRESS with your vm's mac address in ':' notation

```
arp -a | grep _MAC_ADDRESS
```

You should get your VM's IP address.

**With VirtualBox Guest Additions installed**

Another method, easier than the last one, should be through vbox guest additions. If you have guest additions installed, you can simply use:

```
VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate "name_of_VM" | grep /VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP | grep -o -w -P -e '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
```

Or simply

```
VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate "name_of_VM"
```

And search for the IP address

**Installation of Guest Additions** (Internet connection needed)

You can install guest additions through VBoxManage

```
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.12/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.12.vbox-extpack
sudo VBoxManage extpack install ./Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.12.vbox-extpack
```

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. It clearly matches the question. At the same time, I realized that I wanted to ask for a slightly different thing but I used wrong words. So I will edit my question.

Comment: Just modified my answer to respond your edited question.

Comment: Added another method to get your guest IP address, hopefully easier, but you will need guest additions installed on guests, and if you don't, a working internet connection.